Identify two unknown receptacles in 1950s US basement
I have two unknown types of receptacles in my 1950s basement (California, United States).
The first is this square-type receptacle, of which there are two. Both they and their covers have been painted over, so some detail may be lost.

Pulling it out, the wiring looks like this:

The first of the two backs up to the furnace closet and looks like its wire comes out into the closet & runs bare, exposed up the wall to where a dead thermostat is on the opposite side of the wall. It is not directly connected to the modern-looking furnace, and the furnace has its own, modern-looking 1 gang switch to turn if on/off. So I believe this was some sort of rotary switch for the original furnace, but when prior owners replaced the furnace & later installed a whole-home A/C controller, they left this rotary switch / disconnected thermostat defunct.
However, the 2nd rotary switch is less obvious to me. It doesn't appear to exit the room, but I don't have anything in the basement that could have been controlled by it. There's this third receptacle nearby which just has a hole in its cover to the junction box:

which I thought maybe used to be hooked up to some appliance that the 2nd rotary switch controlled, but the color of the 2nd rotary switch's wire (tan) does not match up with either of the two wires coming out of the receptacle with the circle hole (both brown). What could the 2nd rotary switch & the 3rd receptacle with the circle hole have been used for?

If you're a masochist, it is possible to use these "4 prong" wall jacks with modern phones, via an adapter.   Examples https://oldphoneworks.com/collections/adapters-plugs-jacks   (no affifiation)  but you'll need to clean the landlord paint job out of the holes first.

They are for landline phones.
Can probably use the good old rotary phones(one ring a dingy, two ring a dingy) or the newer push button phones, if you want.
The second looks like a coax box for TV antenna connection.

This is correct... altho. only a limited number of people will have any understanding of the "ring a dingy" part.

Lily Tomlin and all of Laugh In were great.

Is it weird then that I pulled the first one and its wire through the wall & it came from the thermostat?

@Drew   Quite possible they got rid of the landline phone and used that box as a junction box to the thermostat.  Phone/thermostat wires are close in gauge, with thermostat wires using usually less voltage than phone wires.  About 24v for thermostat and ~50 to over 100v(ring) for phones.

@Drew not at all - your house is ~75 years old, and likely has a dozen different owners doing different things with the tech of the day.  There are likely many stories and hidden surprises yet-to-find (hopefully all good ones.)
